# Daily server reboot cron?

Tags: server, cron

I want to create a cron job which executes daiy at assigned time and it restart the ubuntu server.

I try to add `reboot` only in cron, but it is not working, whereas it works when I try to execute it from CLI.

Please advise, what command should I add in cron, so that it reboot the server daily at specific time.

Comment: May I ask why you need to reboot a server on a daily basis? This is an indication to me you're doing things wrong. Probably.

Comment: @gertvdijk i've run into situations where you need to reboot a machine regularly. Proprietary software that gets a bad memory leak after ~30 hours of uptime, things like that.

Comment: Gaming servers (cough) Minecraft (cough) often ramleak or somehow fork into hundreds of processes.

Comment: this post is also useful http://askubuntu.com/questions/327015/how-do-i-configure-ubuntu-to-reboot-every-day-at-a-given-time

Comment: If the problem is that some application is leaking memory over time, a better solution wold be to just restart that application service.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to run the following command:

```
/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

with root pirviliges. The way to do it is to use root's crontab, not your user crontab. A `sudo` before the usual crontab command does that:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Tip: You can switch the shell's standard editor for things like `crontab` and `visudo` with `sudo update-alternatives --config editor` and then select the editor of your choice.

Editing the crontab you should add the following line to your file:

```
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command  

@daily root /sbin/shutdown -r now
```

One has to remove "root" if you edited with the command: sudo crontab -e.

The "@daily" here is a shortcut for every day at midnight (equivalent to "0 0 * * *"). By the way - why do you want a daily reboot?

EDIT - see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto for the following: "Crontab commands are generally stored in the crontab file belonging to your user account (and executed with your user's level of permissions). If you want to regularly run a command requiring administrative permissions, edit the root crontab file: sudo crontab -e"

EDIT - thanks to @charlesbridge for his comment - edited answer to include the full path

Comment: With cron, its always safest to use full paths: `/sbin/shutdown -r`

Comment: what is the root do between the time day setting and the command? shouldn't it just be @daily /sbin/shutdown -r now in the root users cronfile? TIA

Comment: The following command has the same effect: `/sbin/reboot`.

Answer (score 1):

in my situation the best working method was

```
systemctl reboot
```